# Checking whether two char vectors are equal in OpenCL?

Tags: c, opencl

I have two char8 vectors. I would like to check if they are equal.

I am getting an error when using the all function:

```
char8 a1 = {'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f','g','h'};
char8 a2 = {'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f','g','h'};
if (isequal(a1, a2)) return 0; // error on this line
```

I also tried:

```
char8 a1 = {'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f','g','h'};
char8 a2 = {'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f','g','h'};
char8 a3 = a1 - a2;
if (all(a3 == 0)) return 0; // error: can't convert from char to int
```

Comment: 1) Provide a [mcve]
2) What error?

Comment: The error is "no matching function call to isequal".

Comment: Is there some version of `isequal` dealing with `char8`? I didn't see one.

Answer (score 1):

OpenCL's `isequal()` function is [only defined for the floating-point vector & scalar types](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenCL/sdk/1.2/docs/man/xhtml/isequal.html), so that's why your first approach doesn't work.

Your second approach is on the right track; I believe the problem is you're comparing a `char8` (`a3`) to an `int` (`0`). You actually shouldn't need to subtract the vectors, equality should work fine (vector comparison operators yield `-1` for true, so `all()`'s test for MSB should work.):

```
char8 a1 = {'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f','g','h'};
char8 a2 = {'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f','g','h'};
if (all(a1 == a2))
    return 0;
```

Alternatively, you could change the last line of your subtraction approach to:

```
if (all(a3 == (char8)(0))) return 0;
```

This should also work as you're comparing a `char8` with another `char8` (with all 0s) again.

Comment: If you're going to downvote my answer, please at least leave a comment giving a reason. (Do the suggested approaches not work? Can the answer be improved in some way?)

Answer (score -2):

you need to use `memcmp` function instead.

`#define MIN(x,y) ((x) > (y) ? (y) : (x))`

`memcmp(a,b, MIN(sizeof(a), sizeof(b)));`

> ```
>    #include <string.h>
>
>    int memcmp(const void *s1, const void *s2, size_t n);
> ```
>
> The memcmp() function returns an integer less than, equal to, or
>   greater than zero if the first n bytes of s1 is found, respectively,
>   to be less than, to match, or be greater than the first n bytes of
>   s2.
>
> For a nonzero return value, the sign is determined by the sign of
>   the    difference between the first pair of bytes (interpreted as
>   unsigned    char) that differ in s1 and s2.
>
> If n is zero, the return value is zero.

Full description: http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/memcmp.3.html

Comment: I am not sure if this answer covers the openCL touch of the question.

Comment: This gives me the error, "Implicit declaration of a function 'memcmp' is illegal in OpenCL"

Comment: @SupremeGrandRuler You need header `<string.h>` for `memcmp`

Comment: @Gerhardh This doesn't work in OpenCL. There is no C standard library available.